# Filter our rows where all the grouped elements are equal to zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, pandas-groupby

my df:

```
id1 id2  uid . . . 
 1  100   0
 1  101 1000
 1  101 1000
 2  102   0
 2  103   0
 3  104 1002
 3  104 1002
 3  104 1002
 3  104   0
 3  105   0
 3  106   0
 4  107   0
 4  107   0
 4  108   0
 4  108   0
```

I would to group by `id1` and filter out `id1`s where all the `uid`s are zero.

I tried the following:

```
df = df.groupby(by = 'id1').filter(lambda x: x['uid'].sum() > 0).reset_index(drop = True)
```

But the issue is that it sums up the non-zero `uid`s and creates random `uid`s by doing so.

Desired result:

```
id1 id2  uid . . . 
 1  100   0
 1  101 1000
 1  101 1000
 3  104 1002
 3  104 1002
 3  104 1002
 3  104   0
 3  105   0
 3  106   0
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Seems to give the desired output for me: https://akuiper.com/console/QCe4uhUhNK-_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the "uid"s not equal to 0; then select the corresponding "id1"s by transforming the `max`, which assigns True if for an "id1", the corresponding set of "uid"s contain a non-0 (so for example, "id1"=4 is dropped):

```
out = df[df['uid'].ne(0).groupby(df['id1']).transform('max')]
```

Output:

```
    id1  id2   uid
0     1  100     0
1     1  101  1000
2     1  101  1000
5     3  104  1002
6     3  104  1002
7     3  104  1002
8     3  104     0
9     3  105     0
10    3  106     0
```